# Sharepoint 2013 searching profiles

Tags: people-search, content-search-web-part, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to set up my sites search. We have a page called myprofile.aspx where we can see the profile information obtained from the sharepoint Rest API user profile service based on query string values.

For example:

> abc/def/mrprofile.aspx?p=accountname

We use this "account name" and call Sharepoint Rest API to display user profile properties on that page.

Now I would like to set up a search page in which I would like to search for a user and the above url *(abc/def/mrprofile.aspx?p=accountname)* should be displayed in the search results.

How can such a mapping be achieved?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an out of the box people search web part on a page the correct parameter is "k". So you could send them to mysearchpage.aspx?k=accountname. You could also ensure you get your user with a Managed Property like k='AccountName=accountname' (IIRC the AccountName managed property is mapped to the Windows Identity. I am doing this from memory.)